# Apache redirect after a rewrite

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to properly do this.  I'm hosting a domain that used to have a website also on the same server, however the website has now been moved to a different machine, but they want to keep the domain hosted on our DNS.  Rather than changing the DNS record right now, I'm trying to figure out how to do a proxy redirect but I'm having some trouble.

Right now, I'm using the RewriteEngine to rewrite the URL as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www\.domain\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)              http://www.domain.org/$1 [L,R]
```

This is in case someone looks up the website simply by http://domain.org it will get rewritten to http://www.domain.com - that works fine.

Now I need to redirect it to go to an IP address with a username:

```
http://111.222.333.444/~user
```

Rather than simply redirecting it to that address, I'd like to do a proxy where the domain will still be visible in the browser's address bar, while also keeping the above rule in place.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mod_proxy is enabled and do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://111.222.333.444/~user
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How would that work with the previously mentioned rule that I want to keep in place?

Comment: You can either use "ServerAlias www.domain.org" or setup another vHost redirecting to the .com site.

Comment: I just noticed my mistake above ...  My apologies.  The redirect is to go from domain.org to www.domain.org - NOT .com.  It's so that when you type domain.org in your browser, the server redirects you to www.domain.org ...  So disregard the .com in my rules in my original message, it should've been .org.  Sorry.

Comment: There is no need to use mod_rewrite for that. Just setup another vhost redirecting from d.org to www.d.org. See: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7889771